# Determine if Google account is premium

Tags: google-docs-api

My application uses Google Docs (through OAuth) to open and save files. Now when uploading Microsoft Office documents to Google Docs they are converted to native Google Docs, which works for both free and premium Google accounts.

Given that I use OAuth is there any way to reliably determine whether the account is premium and supports uploading of unconverted documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should be looking for

```
<docs:feature>
    <docs:featureName>upload_any</docs:featureName>
</docs:feature>
```

in metadata feed for the account: [Metadata Feed](http://code.google.com/intl/ja/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#MetaDataFeed).

Look at [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-documents-list-api/browse_thread/thread/bb0ed8852e4155a5) if there are problems with getting it working.